# Keep touchZoom centered?

Tags: leaflet

I am using Leaflet in a mobile app and want to get rid of the two zooming buttons in the top corner, but I need the exact same effect (zooming without the possibility of panning around with it) but using a pinching gesture. Alas, the default pinching gesture does not keep the view centred!

I don't know why, but keeping the zoom centred when using the mousewheel or doubleclick [are available options for the map object](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-dragging):

> If passed 'center', double-click zoom will zoom to the center of the view regardless of where the mouse was.
>
> If passed 'center', it will zoom to the center of the view regardless of where the mouse was.

But not for touchZoom, I tried. maybe the nice people at Leaflet thought the effect doesn't "feel" nice, but I really wish I could try it nonetheless and judge it by myself.

Anyone knows how to get a similar effect? I don't really want to end up calling setView() at every "zoom" event call, if that even was an option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I could use the [maxBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxbounds) option. If you set both corners on a single point (the one you'd use for `setView`, for example), the map won't be able to pan away from it.